# Using Sybase TSQL to generate XML

Tags: xml, t-sql, nested, sybase

I have recently found out about the **FOR XML** command in Sybase SQL to convert the output directly to XML format which looks like a blessing. However, I am unable to find a way of generating a multi-level, or nested, XML output.

Can it be done please, and if so could any useful examples be given? My SQL is good but my **FOR XML** is obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Sybase at all... but I've often solved the problem of getting valid XML by adding `FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS` to the end of my SQL query.

Further on this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54584/Controlling-the-XML-output-when-using-the-FOR-XML

Comment: Appreciated, but Sybase SQL doesn't seem to like it one little bit. Or I'm doing it wrong, which is also likely.